# How to call ::TerminateProcess (windows) for a QProcess in Qt?

Tags: qt, ssh, rsync

I really need to kill a QProcess and all its childs on windows and I understand windows's API `::TerminateProcess` is my best friend. I have tried taskkill but it still does't kill the process.

```
QProcess::execute("taskkill /f /t ssh.exe");
QProcess::execute("taskkill /f /t rsync.exe"); // no luck
```

So `::TerminateProcess` is the most brute way of killing a processing but how do I get handle of the QProcess that I started so I can use it?

Here is my code.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    syncProcess = new QProcess(this);

    connect( syncProcess, SIGNAL( finished(int)), this, SLOT( syncFinished(int)) );
}

void MainWindow::sync()
{
    QString rsync_cmd = QString("rsync/rsync -a root@%1:/root '%2'").arg( ip ).arg( destPath );

    syncProcess->start( rsync_cmd ); 

    _syncInProgress = true;
}
```

This starts `rsync` which in turns starts `ssh`. If user cancels, I want to kill both of them. Even when I called the `taskkill`above for both ssh and rsync, they don't get terminated and continue syncing.

So my question is how to get handle of QProcess and more ultimately how can I kill/terminate rsync and ssh processes?

I only want my solution to work on Windows 7, other platforms are not important.

▼**Update**▼

Here is my code where I am cancelling. I have `QProgressDialog`when user clicks `cancel` button, the following function gets called where I try to kill the process but it survives.

```
void MainWindow::syncProgressCancelled()
{

    disconnect( syncProgress.data(), SIGNAL( canceled()), this, SLOT(syncProgressCancelled()) );

    _syncInProgress = false;

    syncProgress->close(); // this just closed toe progress dialog

    // make sure to kill the underlying ssh or rsync if running

//    QProcess::execute("taskkill /f /t ssh.exe");
//    QProcess::execute("taskkill /f /t rsync.exe");

    syncProcess->terminate(); // kill doesn't work either

}
```

Comment: I tried this but both `kill` and `terminate` didn't work. I have edited the post to include the function where I am terminating the process.

Comment: Also, you've got a working example in my answer. Start with that. Check that it works for you. Then you can build on that.

Comment: Sorry, you have to be more explicit about what process is not killed. It works in the example I gave if I start the application itself as the subprocess.

Comment: @KubaOber the `rsync` and 'ssh` are not getting killed which are started by `QProcess`. In my case it is copying a lot of files so it takes a while. In your case rsync maybe just waiting for password or something, if you supply real values so it copies files from somewhere (non-local location), than it will not get killed.

Comment: Provide links to the exact binary that you're using as `rsync` and `ssh`.

Comment: @KubaOber http://www.mingw.org/ run the installer, select rsync and ssh components.

Comment: Great - now I have a chance at actually reproducing the issue. Such details are vitally important.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting a non-detached process, then `QProcess` gives you all the tools you need. You can use either `QProcess::kill` or `QProcess::terminate`, as needed. No winapi needed.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPushButton kill("Kill");
  kill.show();
  QProcess process;
  process.start("rsync ...");
  QObject::connect(&kill, &QPushButton::clicked, &process, &QProcess::kill);
  QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::finished, &app, &QCoreApplication::quit);
  return app.exec();
}
```

If you were to start a detached process, then the `startDetached` method can output a `pid` that you can use with native api.

Comment: I updated my post with code and its really the same thing that you wrote except mine is in class but its not working.